# How can i push number "125" to char array?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I want to push some number to array of char. But the number is big, for exameple lets take '125'.
I tried 3 cause:
1) Integer:

```
char arr[2];
    int number = 125;
    int *pNumber = &number;
    memcpy(arr + 0, pNumber, sizeof(arr)); 
    cout << (int)arr[0] << endl;
```

and the ouput is:

```
125
```

So this is amazing !!! but if i change the number for bigger than 127, so the result is bad.For 128 is -128, 129 is -127 ..... How is it possible? Is there a way for fix it? As for me the size of char is smaller than 128.

2)char array:

```
   char arr[2];
   char *arr2 = new char[3];
   arr2[0] = '8';
   arr2[1] = '9';
   arr2[2] = '\0';
   memcpy(arr + 0, (char*)arr2, sizeof(pole)); 
   cout << arr[0] << endl;
```

However thisone prints just the fisrt sign '8'. Can i fix it ? or this is bad way again?

3) string:

```
char arr[2];
string s = "125";
string *ps = &s;
memcpy(pole + 0, ps, sizeof(pole));
cout << pole[0] << endl;
```

This output is some sign, which i can not recognize..

Please, can you tell me, how i can do it? Thank you!

Comment: You can't store more than 127 in a signed char, I understood nothing of what you want to do.

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained what you actually wanted to happen. When you push, say, 128 to an array of characters, what do you want to actually happen?

Comment: When you go over 127 for a signed char it's overflowing to negative values. use unsigned char for no negatives and a max of 255

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell, but I think this is what you are looking for

```
char arr[15];
int number = 125;
sprintf( arr, "%d", number );
```

which will work for any number up to 2 billion (2^31).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want that the number=125 was at the first index, so: arr[0] = 125. I know, that like this its not possible, however if there will be something like arr[0] = pointer(for number). As for me, i should use "memcpy".. and i am still trying :]

Answer (score 0):

I have it! I thought like this:

```
char arr[10];
int number = 125;
int * pNumber = &number;
memcpy(arr + 0, (char*)pNumber, sizeof(int));
char *out = arr + 0;
int *a = ((int*)out);
cout << *a << endl;
```

And now the ouput is 125 :] 
Thanks

Comment: cout << 125 << endl; does the same thing.